# Is there a way to disable some vagrant commands for specific VM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant

I'm working with Amazon EC2 instance using plugin [vagrant-aws](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws) for Vagrant. I connect instance with `vagrant up --provider=aws` and... commands like `vagrant halt`, `vagrant reload` and aspecially `vagrant destroy` become very dangerous in my situation, becouse they can ruin the instance!
So, question is **how can I disable some vagrant commands** (for example in Vagrantfile)**?** I need to give configured Vagrantfile to another developers, so there is a chance they can shut down important server. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the plugin maker.

By using the [vagrant-triggers](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) plugin, you can write in your `Vagrantfile` something like:

```
config.trigger.reject [:destroy, :halt]
```

Comment: I wanted to prevent myself from accidentally destroying my VM as I've yet to puppetize things.  This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the easiest way to solve this problem is to create a policy with:

```
{
    "Action": [
        "ec2:TerminateInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:RebootInstances",
        "ec2:StartInstances",
        "ec2:RunInstances"
         ],
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

Maybe it will be useful for someone. Thanks!

Comment: could you please specify where and how this policy should be created

Comment: log into your amazon account, in EC2 dashboard:

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [Vagrant ManagedServers](https://github.com/tknerr/vagrant-managed-servers) plugin. It is designed to manage and share cloud based instances between developers, even in production.

Note that normally (without the aforementioned plugin) sharing just the Vagrantfile is not enough to get access to the same EC2 instance. The instance details are stored in the .vagrant directory, and each developers spins up a server of their own.